# Why is my library's dependency required in user applications?

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management

I have a library that is using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus#add-eventbus-to-your-project) for events. As I want to expose their classes (such as `EventBus` or `Subscribe`), I declared the dependency as `api`:

```
api 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
```

When building an app with the library's source as dependency (`implementation project("library")`), all works fine. But when using the library from Gradle or as a local Jar, it results in the following:

```
    > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac 
src/main/java/app/MediaActivity.java:18: error: package org.greenrobot.eventbus does not exist
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
                              ^
src/main/java/app/MediaActivity.java:19: error: package org.greenrobot.eventbus does not exist
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;
                              ^
app/src/main/java/app/MediaActivity.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
    @Subscribe
     ^
  symbol:   class Subscribe
  location: class MediaActivity
```

Adding the EventBus dependency to the app solves the issue, but users should not need to add the library's dependencies manually (this problem happens with another dependency too).

#### What's wrong here? How should I declare the dependency to expose it to user apps?

Answer (score 2):

> But when using the library from Gradle or as a local Jar, it results in the following:

A JAR has no information about transitive dependencies. IOW, a JAR does not tell consumers of that JAR "hey, I need these other libraries".

> What's wrong here?

It would appear that you are using a bare JAR (e.g., via `implementation fileTree()`).

> How should I declare the dependency to expose it to user apps?

Publish the JAR as an artifact to an artifact repository. The artifact metadata — such as the POM file for a Maven-style repository — will have information about transitive dependencies.